# MongoDb ReplicaSet in container, accessable on bridge and host network

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am running 3 MongoDB instances in a container named `mongodb-local`, and initiating them as a replica set with the command:

```
mongo --port 27020 --eval 'rs.initiate({_id: "rs1", members: [ { _id: 0, host: "mongodb-local:27018"}, { _id: 1, host: "mongodb-local:27019"}, { _id: 2, host: "mongodb-local:27020"} ] })'
```

This allows the MongoDB instances to talk to other services on the bridge network as `mongodb://mongodb-local:27018,mongodb-local:27019,mongodb-local:27020/?replicaSet=rs1`

However, I also want to connect to the MongoDB replica-set from the host/public.  I have published the 3 ports there, however attempting to connect to and use `mongodb://localhost:27018,localhost:27019,localhost:27020/?replicaSet=rs1` fails because the replicas know eachother as `mongodb-local`, which is not resolvable to the host.

Errors for example in the c# driver such as:

```
One or more errors occurred. (A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27018" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27018", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
```

or in the shell

```
...>mongo mongodb://localhost:27020,localhost:27019,localhost:27018/?replicaSet=rs1

MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27020,localhost:27019,localhost:27018/?replicaSet=rs1
2020-07-22T11:24:23.036+0100 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for rs1/localhost:27020,localhost:27019,localhost:27018
2020-07-22T11:24:23.042+0100 I NETWORK  [js] Successfully connected to localhost:27018 (1 connections now open to localhost:27018 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-07-22T11:24:23.042+0100 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to localhost:27019 (1 connections now open to localhost:27019 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-07-22T11:24:23.046+0100 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to localhost:27020 (1 connections now open to localhost:27020 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-07-22T11:24:23.048+0100 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] changing hosts to rs1/mongodb-local:27018,mongodb-local:27019,mongodb-local:27020 from rs1/localhost:27018,localhost:27019,localhost:27020
2020-07-22T11:24:28.563+0100 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set rs1
2020-07-22T11:24:28.563+0100 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set rs1. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2020-07-22T11:24:32.072+0100 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set rs1
2020-07-22T11:24:32.072+0100 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set rs1. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 2 checks in a row.
2020-07-22T11:24:35.581+0100 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set rs1
2020-07-22T11:24:35.581+0100 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set rs1. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 3 checks in a row.
2020-07-22T11:24:39.091+0100 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set rs1
2020-07-22T11:24:39.092+0100 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set rs1. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 4 checks in a row.
2020-07-22T11:24:39.097+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: connect failed to replica set rs1/localhost:27020,localhost:27019,localhost:27018 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Conversely, I could initiate the replica set as:

```
mongo --port 27020 --eval 'rs.initiate({_id: "rs1", members: [ { _id: 0, host: "localhost:27018"}, { _id: 1, host: "localhost:27019"}, { _id: 2, host: "localhost:27020"} ] })'
```

Which will allow connections from the host machine/public, and by coincedence since the replicas are all running on the same container, they can also talk to eachother.

However, other services cannot connect with `mongodb://mongodb-local:27018,mongodb-local:27019,mongodb-local:27020/?replicaSet=rs1`, with a similar error.

This would also fail if I wanted to put each replica on a separate container.

I believe this is because the client receives the replica-set record after connecting and expects that to be available on the network it is connecting from?  This is not a great assumption if so.

How can I initiate the replica-set on the bridge network and also allow connections from outside the bridge network?

Comment: did you try this https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb/ ? its provide such configuration out of the box

Comment: bitnami/mongodb uses the machine ip (which may or may not be public or static) or optionally you can specify a publicly resolvable hostname using `MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME`.  Clients must be able to reach the ip or resolve the hostname, even if connecting using a uri on the bridge network.  This would not work if for example such clients had no public network access (internal: true) on the bridge network.

Comment: Tried with bitnami, same problems.  Please post an example if you know how.

Comment: You need to use hostnames that resolve to addresses that are accessible from all clients, or you can use split horizon dns where the hosts resolve to different addresses depending on where they are queried from.